# Controlling JavaScript from user's end

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, com

I am working on a website where I have to repetitively attach an image file one by one and click submit for it to be uploaded. I looked at site's JavaScript code and found the right buttons, and I even used AHK's COM object [tutorial here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80590-how-to-automate-a-web-login-requires-ie/) to click() those buttons using JavaScript. I wanted to know is there any sophisticated way to control webpages using javascripts from user's end on browser other than Internet Explorer?

(I am looking for something better than putting focus on url-bar, and typing javascript:alert())

Comment: [This may be of interest.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)

Comment: @Pointy, thank you! Greasemonkey can even bind hotkeys. But, with AHK I could create a logfile, how to do that with greasemonkey?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Greasemonkey can make local log files; I'm familiar with it but only a little.